# Spring MongoDB : Match passed values in nested array

Tags: spring, mongodb

I'm trying to match passed array values in request to a nested array in database.

Here is my document structure:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("61b026e5eb557640ff892826"),
  "pack_uuid" : "e20ed273-50d9-46ac-a733-815e6c51294e",
  "pack_name" : "CarePack",
  "industries" : [ 
    21, 
    22,
    23,
    24,
    25
  ]
}
```

I want a query to find all objects that have industry values 23, 25 (order does not matter). I tried following but it will match if all values of industries are passed.

```
Criteria criteriaKeyIndustry = Criteria.where("industries").all(searchPackDTO.getIndustries());
```

**searchPackDTO.getIndustries()** returns a List<Integer>

I also tried this but didn't work:

```
Criteria criteriaKeyIndustry = Criteria.where("industries").in(searchPackDTO.getIndustries());
```

I couldn't understand how to use **elemmatch**

Comment: Since your array is simple scalar values you don't need to use ElemMatch.

Comment: Obviously using ".all()" requires all entities to exist.

Comment: I would have expected ".in()" to work.  Can you please expand on the use of ".in()"?